# Getting this error in Storm Nimbus: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-storm, nimbus

```
2020-05-27 06:07:52.060 o.a.s.z.AclEnforcement main [INFO] SECURITY IS DISABLED NO FURTHER CHECKS...
2020-05-27 06:07:52.149 o.a.s.u.Utils main [ERROR] Received error in thread main.. terminating server...
java.lang.Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/librocksdbjni15718346147278608878.so: /tmp/librocksdbjni15718346147278608878.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:653) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:632) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.lambda$createDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler$2(Utils.java:1014) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1055) [?:?]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1050) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2001) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/librocksdbjni15718346147278608878.so: /tmp/librocksdbjni15718346147278608878.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2617) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:767) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1831) ~[?:?]
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:?]
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:?]
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:?]
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.metricstore.rocksdb.RocksDbStore.prepare(RocksDbStore.java:67) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.metricstore.MetricStoreConfig.configure(MetricStoreConfig.java:33) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:531) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:474) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:468) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launchServer(Nimbus.java:1307) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launch(Nimbus.java:1332) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.main(Nimbus.java:1337) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
```

When starting Nimbus process I got this error. Storm UI is working fine but Nimbus fails. Supervisors's Process is also working properly.

Answer (score 0):

please try to remount your /tmp directory.

I was setting storm cluster in centOS7
I have face the exact problem so i tried this command and it works for me .

**sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec**